# Adding a customized version of bundler as a dependency in a Gemfile

Tags: ruby, bundler

How can I make a typical gem setup (as generated by `bundle gem`) run a customize version of bundler?

I've added:

```
#group :development do
  gem "bundler", github: 'pjump/bundler'
#end
```

to my Gemfile (with or without the the hash symbols), and bundle install works, but bundle exec keeps telling me that the `bundler` repo is not yet checked out. The only way I can make it work for now is by installing the customized version with `gem istall` and not specifying a `bundler` dependency in the package at all.

Comment: I'm curious - what's the reason for putting bundler in the Gemfile? (If I need a custom version of bundler, I provide it on the system e.g. via ansible, rather than in the Gemfile; I consider bundler to be more like system software e.g. apt, dpkg, brew, than like a typical application dependency)

Comment: IDK. `bundle gem` does add it to the gemspec as a dependency. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler isn't able to bootstrap itself from a `Gemfile`, so adding a customized version to your `Gemfile` will not do what you want. Installing it with `gem install` is the correct solution (or running `rake install` from the forked Bundler repo directory, which builds and installs the gem in one step).